# How to merge two collections and let result end up in user defined field?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Suppose I have two collections: one main collection and one collection containing meta data. The meta data has additional (volatile) data that I don't want to have in my main collection.

What I'd like to do next is to merge this meta data with the main collection. This is possible since they both use the same `_id`. However I don't want all meta data to end up in the main document, I want to to end up in a field named `meta`. Like this:

```js
// Main record
{
  _id: 1234,
  varA: "foo",
  varB: "bar"
}

// Meta record
{
  _id: 1234,
  metaA: "cafe",
  metaB: "babe"
}
```

The merge should end up with

```
// Merged record
{
  _id: 1234,
  varA: "foo",
  varB: "bar",
  meta:
  { 
    metaA: "cafe",
    metaB: "babe"
  }
}
```

Obviously I could manually iterate through all documents and combine them myself, but that's slow and I'm sure this can be solved using aggregation stages.

I already tried various options of `$merge`, all to no avail. If anyone has an idea, please let me know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I already tried various options of `$merge`, all to no avail. If anyone has an idea, please let me know.

If I'm understanding the situation appropriately, there is no option built into the `$merge` stage that would achieve your goal directly. Rather, the solution here is going to be in shaping the data via preceding stages in the aggregation prior to the `$merge` itself.

Specifically, the `meta` record that you currently have looks like this:

```
{
  _id: 1234,
  metaA: "cafe",
  metaB: "babe"
}
```

What you need it to be in order to use `$merge` directly looks something more like this:

```
{ 
  _id: 1234, 
  meta: { 
    metaA: 'cafe', 
    metaB: 'babe' 
  } 
}
```

Such a transformation can be achieved with a pipeline such as:

```
[
  { $addFields: {meta:'$$ROOT'} },
  { $unset:'meta._id' }, 
  { $project:{_id:1, meta:1} }
]
```

Putting this altogether and appending the `$merge` (with default values) yields the change to the document(s) in the `main` collection as desired:

```
> db.main.find()
[ 
  { _id: 1234, varA: 'foo', varB: 'bar' } 
]
> db.meta.find()
[ 
  { _id: 1234, metaA: 'cafe', metaB: 'babe' } 
]
> db.meta.aggregate([
  {$addFields:{meta:'$$ROOT'}},
  {$unset:'meta._id'}, 
  {$project:{_id:1, meta:1}},
  {$merge:{into:'main'}}
])

> db.main.find()
[
  {
    _id: 1234,
    varA: 'foo',
    varB: 'bar',
    meta: { metaA: 'cafe', metaB: 'babe' }
  }
]
```